# Multiple React components not triggering Redux state dispatch in order

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
// Component
function FooComponent() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const reduxState = useSelector((state) => state.store);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(updateStore({FooComponent: reduxState.FooComponent + 1}));
    return () => {
      dispatch(updateStore({FooComponent: reduxState.FooComponent - 1}));
    };
  }, []);

  return <></>;
}

// Redux Slice
const reduxSlice = createSlice({
  name: "reduxStore",
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {
    updateStore: (state, action) => {
      state = action.payload;
    },
  },
});
```

I have this React component and Redux slice (heavily simplified for this question). My React app renders *N* of these `FooComponents` and when it mounts, it triggers a dispatch through the useEffect. The dispatch action should change the value of the reduxState based on its current state. However since all *N* of these components are mounted at the same time, they all see the same "current" redux state i.e. they all see `reduxState.FooComponent = reduxState.FooComponent + 1` as `reduxState.FooComponent = 0 + 1`. As a result, after my *N* components are rendered the redux store shows `reduxState.FooComponent = 1` instead of `reduxState.FooComponent = N`. Is there a way I can make ensure the dispatches are triggered one after the other so the component can have the actual current Redux state? I want to minimize changing logic in the Redux slice as possible since it is used by many other components.

I know I could probably create a Redux slice action that increments the count but this example is just a simple version of what I want.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much the perfect example why we recommend against setter actions like your `updateStore`. Calculations should generally take place inside the store, while actions should only be "events" that describe to your store what happened.

Your logic depends on React rerendering in-between each of those dispatches so your `reduxState` constant can be recreated with a new snapshot of the state - and that doesn't happen, so you make calculations based on stale state.

What we recommend instead is that you have a `incrementStore` and `decrementStore` action. Do your actual calculation inside the reducer, because it will always be up-to-date there.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(incrementStore("FooComponent"));
  return () => {
    dispatch(decrementStore("FooComponent"));
  };
}, []);

//...

// Redux Slice
const reduxSlice = createSlice({
  name: "reduxStore",
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {
    incrementStore(state, action) {
      if (!state[action.payload]) {
        state[action.payload] = 0;
      }
      state[action.payload]++;
    },
    decrementStore(state, action) {
      if (!state[action.payload]) {
        state[action.payload] = 0;
      }
      state[action.payload]--;
    },
  },
});
```

Also give a read to the [Redux Style Guide](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/), it has a few points on this topic.